# Rails 5 devise omniauth-facebook Error: Sorry, something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I am following Devise's official guide from top to [this section](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview#logout-links). My `CALLBACK_URL` is `http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback`, which I think might be the problem but I'm not sure. When I click on Sign in with Facebook, I run into this error:
**Sorry, something went wrong.**
on this link:
`https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?client_id=193217371133539&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=user%2Cpublic_repo&state=3913c12e0e4ce8b422732c9159c0fb1fb7351d100487849d`

Rails version: Rails 5.0.0.1
Ruby version(using rbenv): ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @bodacious Yeah, are you stuck with this problem?

Comment: Fixed it now, thanks. For me, the problem was the `scope:` params in the devise config.

Comment: @bodacious yeah same!

Answer (score 5):

For anyone still having this issue, then check your scope, as Akash and Bodacious state above, and modify it to look like this:

```
scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name'
```

This will allow you to get the email field.

Answer (score 3):

I found this
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Facebook returning nulled email

Since July 8th 2015 Facebook changed to api v2.4, you need to add extra info_fields to get email field.

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET", scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name'
```

found solution from here by @techmonster

Comment: You can read more about Facebook permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/