# Facebook Omniauth: Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can. Go Back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, heroku, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

In my rails app, I configured omniauth-facebook, which was working perfectly fine. But after deploying my app to Heroku,https://habitude-helper.herokuapp.com/, now I get an error if I try to Login or Sign up with Facebook.

```
Sorry, something went wrong.

We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

Go Back
```

My site URL on the Facebook app is https://habitude-helper.herokuapp.com/, and link to authorize with Facebook is: 
https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?client_id=27910077666246&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=email&state=59471e0bc7f573b2a1aa55261768443384cbc16e38a73571

I googled a lot about this issue and also changed  source of my omniauth.rb file according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290287/rails-5-devise-omniauth-facebook-error-sorry-something-went-wrong) on stackoverflow.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name'
end
```

But didn't help. I would just like to clarify that I am not using devise. I am using Bcrypt gem.

Any suggestion to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

check redirect_uri, it still pointing to localhost rather than your heroku link.

Change your callback url in Facebook app to heroku link.
Then it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I tried a lot but to modify links but didn't work. Lastly, I just developed the new app on Facebook, used same links and only changed app's id and Secret on Heroku. Works perfectly fine. Still, couldn't understand why I was getting that error!